# Deactivating one script in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point, coordinates, select

I tried the following script in QGIS:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint

class ClickedPoint(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    global pp
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)

    def canvasPressEvent( self, e ):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(self.canvas.mouseLastXY())
        pp.append(point)
        print(pp)

pp = []
canvas_clicked = ClickedPoint( iface.mapCanvas() )
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool( canvas_clicked )
```

This enables me to pick points on the map and output the location. My idea is to stop the selection and output after selecting three points, but I can't find a suitable way to return the mouse default event after selecting three points.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
class ClickedPoint(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas

        # initialize empty QgsPointXY list
        self.points = []

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            
            point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
            
            self.points.append(point)
            
            print(self.points)
            
        if len(self.points) >= 3:
            self.canvas.unsetMapTool(self)



canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
mapTool = ClickedPoint(canvas)
canvas.setMapTool(mapTool)
```